# Trying to destroy uninitialized session in

Tags: session

```
if (!($savedid == $current_session_id)) {
    // 3. hijack then destroy session specified.
    session_id($savedid);
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    session_commit();
    if (session_destroy()) { //eror here
        header("Location: ../../../index.php");
        exit;
    }

    // 4. restore current session id. If don't restore it,
    // your current session will refer to the session you just destroyed!
    session_id($current_session_id);
    session_start();
    session_commit();
}
```

I want to destroy a session based on its id but I get error saying `Trying to destroy uninitialized session in`

How to destroy session using session id?

***UPDATE***

I see I just want a condition saying if session is destroyed i want to direct page to login.. how to check for that?

> I want it like for example user log in in pc1 then log in in pc2 pc1 will be directed to login

Comment: You already destroyed it, why do you want to destroy it again?

Comment: i see i just want a condition saying if session is destroyed i want to direct page to login.. how to check for that? @Al.G. i want it like for example user log in in pc1 then log in in pc2 pc1 will be directed to login

Comment: You have 2 consequitive calls to `session_destroy()`. Just remove the first one :)

Comment: @Al.G. please see updated question and also comment above

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you look here:

```
session_start();
session_destroy(); // Destry
session_commit();
if(session_destroy()){ // Again
```

You'll note that you're trying to destroy the session twice.
The second time you call `session_destroy()` the session is already destroyed and does not exist.

That's why you get an error. Just remove the first call to `session_destroy()`.

**Edit:** as per your question update: you don't need that check (whether the session is destroyed) because you already destroyed it, i.e. you can be sure that there's no session now. (untill you call `session_start()`)

You can check if a session exists by calling `session_id()` - it returns empty string if there's no session:

```
if(!session_id()) { /* No session. Redirect! */ }
else { /* There is a session. Continue. */ }
```

Comment: `how to check for when the session is destroyed so i can direct to login?` also `I want it like for example user log in in pc1 then log in in pc2 pc1 will be directed to login`?

Comment: @BrownmanRevival I didn't see you updated your question when posting my answer, sorry for that. Updated!